In Springboot 3 place holder are not recognised the class
below is the yml config
feign:
   baseurl

@FeignClent(value ="abc.xyz.app", url = "${feign.baseurl}")) 
public interface ExamplseService {
}

I tried to call the feign client url from the application.yml when start the server its not helping it throws the below error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'feign.baseurl' in value "http://${feign.baseurl}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
at

Try testing your url first by injecting the value directly :
@FeignClient(value = "abc.xyz.app", url = "${feign.baseurl:http://default.baseurl.com}")

if it works then there might be a problem  with your application.properties or application.yml file, in that case  add your url to the property file and make sure that it is detected first in run time.
application.yml :
feign:
  baseurl: http://your-base-url.com

or if you have a application.properties :
feign.baseurl=http://your-base-url.com



when i add the url directly it works without issues

then the issue is related to your properties ,what are you using application.properties or yml and could you share it
